# TeamCity MSbuild C++ only build some solutions

Tags: c++, .net-4.0, msbuild, teamcity

In our C++ project we have several solutions, is there a way to only build select solutions in TeamCity. Or is there parameters for msbuild that can accomplish this?

We are using .Net v4.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have several projects in your solution?

You can create a build configuration (something like Debug/Release) for the whole solution und choose which projects should be built in this. You can pass this configuration's name to Teamcity.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to call MSBuild just on your vcxproj files, not the whole sln files.
We use it very often - we have build batch files compiling just vcxproj files. With sln files we work only in VS IDE.